# NetSuite SOAP creating Sales Order with Group Items

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to create Sales Order with Group Items, but I want to add an extra item that is not configured by default as Sub-Item of a Group. I add to request: Group Item, extra item and End Of Group Item. But NetSuite fails with message: `End Of Group without matching Group item at line` and error code: `USER_ERROR`. I couldn't found any description of this error. But I'm not sure about the NetSuite configuration: Maybe it's an error from some Script....

The same error is not just for extra item, I got it if just specify the Group Item, all sub-items (as configured) and End Of Group Item.

Answer (score 0):

It was needed to set the expandGroupItem field to "False", so it's possible to create the Group with any items.
By default I didn't send this field, so I got error.